# If a Go sql.DB is closed, do any unclosed prepared queries get closed?

Tags: postgresql, go, resource-leak

In a Go program using `database/sql`, will any unclosed prepared queries be closed when I `Close` the Postgres DB I'm using?

I've cut this down to a very simple example that does not need the `Prepare` but still shows the question (I believe I could just pass query string to `QueryRow` and get an implicit `Prepare`, but leave it explicit here so I can ask my question):

```
import (
    "database/sql"
)

// Store struct is the postgres
type Store struct {
    pq *sql.DB
}

type Info struct {
    ID      string `json:"id"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
}

func (s *Store) GetInfo(id string) Info {
    defer s.pq.Close()
    stmt, err := s.pq.Prepare(`
            SELECT id, name 
            FROM info 
            WHERE id = $1 LIMIT 1
            `)
    if err != nil {
        return Info{}
    }
    var res Info
    _ = stmt.QueryRow(id).Scan(&res.ID, &res.Name)
    return res
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically `database/sql` [definitely expects you to close your own prepared statements](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare) and doesn't do it for you when the DB or DC is closed.  Further I thought it was possible the server might cleanup the backend memory when your program exits but PostgreSQL will also not clean it up...

https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/446

If you get the implicit Prepare then `database/sql` will handle cleaning up for you but that'll be less efficient if you're running these queries over and over so I'd strongly encourage you to clean up after yourself with a:

```
defer stmt.Close()
```

or similar.